# How can I use a JSON file within a Unit Test when mocking an API response

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, xctest

I would like to load a JSON file and convert it to Data as part of my unit tests.

This is so I may assert how my service handles the response, however I do not want to fill each test case with massive json blocks. I was hoping to keep the file in the same directory as the test case, however trying to run the test throws an exception as the file cannot be found.

```
   func test_ViewDidLoad_CallsContentService() {
        let contentExpectation = expectation(description: "FetchContentEntry")
        let httpClient = HTTPClient()
        let response = createURLResponse(forUrl: "https://foo.bar", withStatusCode: 200)
        httpClient.session = MockURLSession(data: mockContentData, urlResponse: response, error: nil)

.....
}
```

My file is referenced like

```
extension ContentSceneTests {

   .........

    var mockContentData: Data {
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: "./ContentResponse.json"), options: .alwaysMapped)
        return data
    }
}
```

The files are next to each other, eg

ContentSceneTests.swift

ContentResponse.json

Comment: Could you capture the exception (file not found) and print what is the current directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I do something similar in my tests with an extension on `XCTestCase`.

You should be able to use

```
var mockContentData: Data {
    return getData(name: "ContentResponse")
}

func getData(name: String, withExtension: String = "json") -> Data {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let fileUrl = bundle.url(forResource: name, withExtension: withExtension)
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileUrl!)
    return data
}
```